# Bluetooth signal extension

Tags: bluetooth

The problem I'm facing is that my computer is in my office but the signal from the computer's Bluetooth is not strong enough to reach everywhere in the house. If I could use a Bluetooth signal extension in the middle of the living room, that would solve the problem.

The thing is I couldn't find one that described its functionality as signal extension.
Please, could anyone suggest one for me?

Answer (score 0):

Using the terms "Bluetooth range extender" provides dozens to hundreds of results.

One such result is a review of multiple products from various manufacturers:

https://www.msn.com/en-us/lifestyle/rf-buying-guides/best-bluetooth-range-extenders-reviews